# Highlighting a textbox from a mouse click OR tab-key press in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, event-handling

I am trying to highlight an active textbox on my form yellow. I have a total of 60 textboxes. Therefore my idea is that when a user presses on a textbox the background color should turn yellow OR if a user presses tab, whatever textbox it goes to should change to yellow as well. I have the mouse click one working but I can't get the tab key press entrance into the textbox to work. I really need the tab key entrance into the textbox to work since I have my tab indexes lined up perfectly so there is a natural flow.
This is the current code I have which works for highlighting the textboxes with a mouse click on the desired textbox (on the event Enter):

```
private void tbAll_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control tb in this.Controls)
    {
        if (tb is TextBox)
        {
            if (tb.Focused == true)
            {
            ((TextBox)tb).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However if I press tab to go into a textbox, it doesn't highlight yellow, BUT the previous field I just left gets highlighted yellow instead. Anybody know the reason why and a way around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?view=netcore-3.1) and [`Leave`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=netcore-3.1) events - hook all textboxes to the same event handlers for `Enter` and `Leave`, and use the `Sender` argument to change the background color to yellow / white (depending on the event).

Something like this should get you started:

```
private void TextBox_Enter(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}

private void TextBox_Leave(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

This way, it doesn't matter if the user entered the textbox by clicking the mouse or pressing the tab button - as soon as a textbox is focused, it will get a yellow background, and as soon as another control gets the focus, it will return to being white.

Comment: Great idea. This works perfect, did not think to use the sender object which is a lot more simple/practical over the for loop. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :-)